# Text to speech for Angular apps - "allowJs is not set" issue

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, text-to-speech

I'm having trouble integrating [this](https://www.npmjs.com/package/spoken) speech-to-text package into my Angular app. I've added the import statement:

```
import spoken from "../../../node_modules/spoken/build/spoken.js";
```

My project is able to find the spoken.js module but it tells me that "allows is not set".

If I set that value to true in my tsconfig.json file, I then get multiple .js related errors in other files, and I'm unable to build the project. Has anyone encountered something like 
this before?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to import the module at runtime but not check it with TypeScript, try removing the `.js` extension from the import path.

Answer (score 1):

One way would also be to disable type checks for JS files via `"checkJs": false` in your `tsconfig.json`.

Or you could also include the file in `scripts` array in `angular.json` file and in your controller, just declare that variable:

```
declare const spoken: any;
```

(feel free to use something more specific instead of `any` :])

Comment: Did you mean false?